# Determining total number of Columns of CSV using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, csv

I'm working on the NodeJS project, where I'm successfully uploading the CSV file and reading it.

Now i'm looking to extract the total number of the columns in the CSV file, and read the data accordingly.

I've used number of CSV Nodejs modules like Fast-CSV, CSV, Ya-CSV. However, I'm not able to extract the total number of columns and the data of columns using these modules. It would be great help, if you could help me to understand to total number of columns and after this operation read the columns one by one.

Comment: *"However, I'm not able to extract the total number of columns [...] using these modules"* - what does that mean, exactly? The typical CSV module gives you an array for each row in the CSV, and that array has a `length`, and that length is the number of columns in the file. You should also post the code you have, so we can see how you are currently trying to do it.

Comment: Yes I was looking for total number of columns and the extract the data of that particular column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parse, with three lines of code you can parse you CSV file into an array of objects:

```
var parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync');
var yourCSVFile = '"column_1","column_2"\n"value 1","value 2"\n"value 3","value 4"';
var records = parse(yourCSVFile, {columns: true});
```

Then breaking out the columns is easy:

```
var columnResults = {};

for(var row =0; row < records.length; row++){
    for(var column in records[row]){
        if(!columnResults[column]){
            columnResults[column] = [];
        }
        columnResults[column].push(records[row][column]);
    }
}
console.log("Number of columns:", Object.keys(columnResults).length);
console.log("Column names:", Object.keys(columnResults));
console.log("Column data:", columnResults);
```

Output:

> C:\node test.js
>   Number of columns: 2
>   Column names: [ 'column_1', 'column_2' ]
>   Column data: { column_1: [ 'value 1', 'value 3' ], column_2: [ 'value 2', 'value 4' ] }